# How to change/update payment method block html on email templates?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to modify html for credit card payment method. 
This is what i found in **shipment.php** file:

```
$paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())
                ->setIsSecureMode(true);
$paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
$paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
```

This is the source for payment block in the email i received:

```
<dl>
    <dd>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Credit Card Type:</th>
            <td>Visa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Credit Card Number:</th>
            <td>xxxx-1111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Processed Amount:</th>
            <td>$22.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

I want to update html for this block. Can you please advise on the file which i need to check?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to payment module's config.xml inside etc/
2. Check which email template is defined under  node
3. You can find and edit the file found inside app\locale\en_US\template\email
4. Enjoy

Comment: Not much to enjoy, the email templates contain a placeholder `{{var payment_html}}` and thus one can't edit the source there which in turn was probably the reason for the questrion above…